# perl gethostbyname when given IP

Tags: perl, gethostbyname

What happens if a wrong format IP is given to gethostbyname function in perl? One of our scripts was behaving weird when given a wrong format IP (say 1.1.1). On debugging, found that gethostbyname was returning a value when given 1.1.1 for example..any thoughts on this?... In my opinion, gethostbyname should return undef, right?

Comment: Incidentally, for IPv4/IPv6 transparent compatibility you probably want to be calling `Socket::getaddrinfo` rather than the IPv4-only legacy `gethostbyname` resolver.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, Alan and LeoNerd.                          Yes gethostbyname is adding a '0' in the third octet and hence our script is giving a valid output even when the user is entering a wrong 3-octet IP. How to resolve this?

Comment: The user input isn't wrong. If you want to validate that it has -more stringent- format requirements, then you should do so. Perhaps a regexp test or something. But the value is perfectly fine and acceptable by the various address-parsing functions, so I don't see why it should be rejected.

Answer (score 3):

In the beginning of IPv4, before CIDR, addresses were considered to be composed of a network part and a host part. The parts could be written sort of independently in dotted decimal form, and didn't need to be fully decomposed into bytes. So `1.1` is host 1 on network 1, equivalent to `1.0.0.1` or you can also write it as one big 32-bit number: 16777217. There was a time when people used URLs like `http://16777127/` to show how clever they were. That was ruined when spammers started doing it to fool filters.

Somehow, when I ping `1.1.1`, it goes to `1.1.0.1`. I would have guessed `1.0.1.1`. I'm not sure what the rule is to decide how it's broken up exactly.

These old forms are not widely supported (or even understood) anymore, but they haven't been completely rooted out from all the tools and libraries.

P.S. on my first attempt to submit this answer, stackoverflow said:

> Your post contains a link to the invalid domain '16777127'.
>   Please correct it by specifying a full domain or wrapping it in a code block.

Which is sort of what I meant by "not widely supported".

Comment: oops, my numbers didn't match up. 16777127 should have been 16777217. It's 0x01000001. Oh yeah I didn't mention that gethostbyname also historically allowed octal and hex numbers, so 0x01000001 also works as a hostname if some party-pooper hasn't come along and disabled it.

Answer (score 2):

Numeric IPv4 addresses can be written as 1, 2, 3 or 4 numeric components. Each non-final component represents 8 bits (1 octet), and the final represents as many bits required to give the full 32 bit address. Thus, the following all represent the local loopback address:

```
2130706433
127.1
127.0.1
127.0.0.1
```

Each component itself may be written in decimal, hex or octal; thus the following all also encode the same address

```
0x7f000001
127.0x01
0177.0.1
0x7f.0.0.1
```